# how solve writing back value to backend tableview issue in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

In tableview i used a textfield as a delegate component in that  i edited a value in second row its shown in red color but after scrolling down same  color its showing in 20 row  . why ?
check a following code and images

```
TableView {
    id: tableView
    clip: true
    visible: true
    anchors.fill: parent
   flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
    anchors.rightMargin:0
    anchors.topMargin: 50
    anchors.leftMargin: 5
    onWidthChanged: forceLayout()
    onHeightChanged: forceLayout()
     property var columnWidths: [40,150,150,150]
     columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return columnWidths[column] }

   
     rowHeightProvider: function () { return 40 }
     columnSpacing: 4
      model: TableModel {
          TableModelColumn { display: "checked" }
          TableModelColumn { display: "fruitType" }
          TableModelColumn { display: "fruitName" }
          TableModelColumn { display: "fruitPrice" }

          rows: [
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 1,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 2,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 3,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 4,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 5,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 6,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 7,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 8,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 9,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 10,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 11,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 12,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 13,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 14,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 15,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 16,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 17,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 18,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 19,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 20,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 21,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 22,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 23,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 24,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 25,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 26,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 27,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 28,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 29,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 30,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 31,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 32,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 33,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
              {
                  // Each property is one cell/column.
                  checked: 34,
                  fruitType: "Apple",
                  fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                  fruitPrice: 1.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 35,
                  fruitType: "Orange",
                  fruitName: "Navel",
                  fruitPrice: 2.50
              },
              {
                  checked: 36,
                  fruitType: "Banana",
                  fruitName: "Cavendish",
                  fruitPrice: 3.50
              },
         
          ]
      }

      delegate: DelegateChooser {
          DelegateChoice {
              column: 0
              delegate: Text {
                  text: model.display
                  horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                  verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
              }
          }

          DelegateChoice {
              delegate: TextField {
                  id : textss
                  property bool edited : false
                  text: model.display
                  color:edited ?"red" : "#000000"
                  font.family: "Helvetica"
                  font.pixelSize: 12
                  selectByMouse: true
                  clip: true
                  background: Rectangle {
                      color:  "lightgray"
                      border.width: 2
                      anchors.fill: parent

                  }

                  onAccepted: {
                      model.display = textss.text
                       edited = true
                      console.log( model.display)

                  }
              }
          }
      }
```

[i edited a value in second row its shown in red color but after scrolling down same its color showing in 20 row ]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MIJD.png)

[check a 20 line ]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R4N3.png)

how to resolve this issue in tableview ? In qt 6.2.4 version

Comment: don't save state on delegates. They need to be reuseable, the view can delete theme and reinitialize them or furthermore reuse them from cache,

Comment: You would need to have another role on your model for setting the color.

Comment: ya i want  to edit that value and send to backend with respect to that column only not for full row

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, [you **should not** save state on delegates:](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html)

> Delegates are instantiated as needed and may be destroyed at any time. As such, state should never be stored in a delegate.

The usuall way to do this is with another role on the model, which in TableModel case is not feasible, so I advice you to create a C++ QAbstractTableModel.

Having said that here is an ugly example on how to make this work without an aditional role on the model. You should never use this in production.

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels

TableView {
    id: tableView
    clip: true
    visible: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
    anchors.rightMargin:0
    anchors.topMargin: 50
    anchors.leftMargin: 5
    onWidthChanged: forceLayout()
    onHeightChanged: forceLayout()
    property var columnWidths: [40,150,150,150]
    columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return columnWidths[column] }
    property var data_: [
        {
            // Each property is one cell/column.
            checked: true,
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        {
            // Each property is one cell/column.
            
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        {
            // Each property is one cell/column.
            
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        {
            // Each property is one cell/column.
            
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        {
            // Each property is one cell/column.
            
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        {
            // Each property is one cell/column.
            
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        {
            // Each property is one cell/column.
            
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        {
            // Each property is one cell/column.
            
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        {
            // Each property is one cell/column.
            
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        {
            // Each property is one cell/column.
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        {
            // Each property is one cell/column.
            
            fruitType: "Apple",
            fruitName: "Granny Smith",
            fruitPrice: 1.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Orange",
            fruitName: "Navel",
            fruitPrice: 2.50
        },
        {
            
            fruitType: "Banana",
            fruitName: "Cavendish",
            fruitPrice: 3.50
        },
        
    ]
    
    rowHeightProvider: function () { return 40 }
    columnSpacing: 4
    model: TableModel {
        TableModelColumn { display: "checked" }
        TableModelColumn { display: "fruitType" }
        TableModelColumn { display: "fruitName" }
        TableModelColumn { display: "fruitPrice" }
        
        rows: data_
    }
    
    delegate: DelegateChooser {
        DelegateChoice {
            column: 0
            delegate: Text {
                text: model.index + 1
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
        }
        
        DelegateChoice {
            delegate: 
            Rectangle{
                id: rect
                color:  "lightgray"
                border.width: 2
                required property var model
                TextInput {
                    id : textss
                    text: model.display
                    property bool fooNotify: false   
                    color: "#000000" 
                    font.family: "Helvetica"
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    selectByMouse: true
                    clip: true
                    
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    
                    
                    
                    onTextEdited: {
                        model.display = textss.text
                        tableView.data_[rect.model.index] = true
                        color=Qt.binding(
                        function() { if (tableView.data_[rect.model.index]){ return "red"} return "black"}
                        )
                        
                        
                        console.log( model.display)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I have found that `ListView` + `ListModel` is superior to `TableView` + `TableModel`. This is because (1) `TableModel` is a lab's feature, (2) there are challenges having updates to `TableModel` seen in `TableView`, and (3) there are customization issues with `TableView`. With `ListView`, you know what you're going to get and it has been around for a lot longer than `TableView`.

I had a look at your data and found it was really 3 records repeated, and you were not using the `checked` property as intended, so, I replaced it with the built-in `index`. I also added support to supply different editing between string vs floating point input.

Also, there were issues with the "write back concept" and your use of editing. Since there is no way to track editing for every cell value unless you declared it in the model itself. Instead, I declared a `modified` property that applies to the entire row. You can see the moment any cell is modified, it triggers the entire row to be flagged as modified.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ListView {
        clip: true
        width: 540
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.rightMargin:0
        anchors.topMargin: 50
        anchors.leftMargin: 5
        model: MyListModel { }
        delegate: RowLayout {
            Label {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 40
                text: (index+1)
                color: modified ? "red" : "black"
            }
            MyTextField { role: "fruitName" }
            MyTextField { role: "fruitType" }
            MyFloatField { role: "fruitPrice" }
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { width: 20; policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn }
    }
}

// MyTextField.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
TextField {
    Layout.preferredWidth: 150
    property string role: "fruitName"
    property string roleType: "string"
    text: model[role]
    color: modified ? "red" : "black"
    onAccepted: {
        model[role] = text;
        modified = true;
    }
}

// MyFloatField.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
MyTextField {
    role: "fruitPrice"
    roleType: "float"
    property int precision: 2
    text: model[role].toFixed(precision)
    onAccepted: {
        model[role] = parseFloat(text);
        modified = true;
    }
}


// MyListModel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
ListModel {
    function appendFruit(fruitType, fruitName, fruitPrice) {
        append( { fruitType, fruitName, fruitPrice, modified: false } );
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            appendFruit( "Apple", "Granny Smith", 1.50 );
            appendFruit( "Orange", "Navel", 2.50 );
            appendFruit( "Banana", "Cavendish", 3.50 );
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)